# loadImage function in qtQuick source code

Tags: c++, qt, canvas, qml, qtquick2

In qtQuick Source. There is one line of code in the function loadImage:

```
QQuickPixmap* pix = new QQuickPixmap();
```

If I call this function as much as possible on the canvas.The memory allocated by the operating system to this application will be filled, which will cause the picture to fail.I'd like to ask if there is any problem with this source code?

```
void QQuickCanvasItem::loadImage(const QUrl& url)
{

    Q_D(QQuickCanvasItem);
    QUrl fullPathUrl = d->baseUrl.resolved(url);
    if (!d->pixmaps.contains(fullPathUrl)) {
        QQuickPixmap* pix = new QQuickPixmap();
        QQmlRefPointer<QQuickCanvasPixmap> canvasPix;
        canvasPix.adopt(new QQuickCanvasPixmap(pix));
        d->pixmaps.insert(fullPathUrl, canvasPix);

        pix->load(qmlEngine(this)
                , fullPathUrl
                , QQuickPixmap::Cache | QQuickPixmap::Asynchronous);
        if (pix->isLoading())
            pix->connectFinished(this, SIGNAL(imageLoaded()));
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

```
void QQuickCanvasItem::loadImage(const QUrl& url)
{

    Q_D(QQuickCanvasItem);
    QUrl fullPathUrl = d->baseUrl.resolved(url);
    if (!d->pixmaps.contains(fullPathUrl)) {
        QQuickPixmap* pix = new QQuickPixmap();
        QQmlRefPointer<QQuickCanvasPixmap> canvasPix;
        canvasPix.adopt(new QQuickCanvasPixmap(pix));
        d->pixmaps.insert(fullPathUrl, canvasPix);

        pix->load(qmlEngine(this)
                , fullPathUrl
                , QQuickPixmap::Cache | QQuickPixmap::Asynchronous);
        if (pix->isLoading())
            pix->connectFinished(this, SIGNAL(imageLoaded()));
    }
}
```